Understanding turn-on current for opto SSR
This table below in a 1 Form A SSR (VORA1010M4) datasheet is confusing me. It shows the max turn-on current as 2mA but then the forward voltage test current is 5mA. In the table for turn-on times I also see a test current of 5mA.



In another 1 Form A SSR datasheet (CPC1017N) I see a max turn-on current of 1mA and then a note stating "to activate, a minimum LED drive current of 3mA is recommended"
When calculating the series resistor do I use the max or the recommended/test value for current?


It shows the max turn-on current as 2mA but then the forward voltage test current is 5mA

What it means is that to guarantee that the SSR activates you need a current of 2 mA. This is the bare minimum needed for successfully guaranteeing 100% of all SSRs activate.
On the other side of the coin is the guaranteed deactivation level of 50 μA
The 5 mA is higher of course but, if you aim for this (rather than the bare minimum of 2 mA) the rise/fall specifications (for example) in the data sheet will be met. However, if on resistance is important to your application, you may choose the drive the diode at 10 mA.

When calculating the series resistor do I use the max or the
recommended/test value for current?

I would go for a diode current of 5 mA and choose the resistor accordingly.
